# Azure build is not able to access projects in repository in another project

Tags: azure-devops

My base project ("WinningsAPI") references projects that are a repository of another project ("Winnings").  This work well on my computer using Visual Studio 2022.  Both projects are also in Azure DevOps and both have the same organization owner.  When I attempt to build the WinningsAPI in DevOps, I get a message that it cannot find the files in Winnings. The message is

```
##[error]D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\1\Winnings\Winnings.CoreData\Winnings.CoreData.csproj" was not found.
```

I have set the security of the Winning repository to allow everyone in the organization to read its files.  Are there other settings that are needed to allow a project access projects in other repositories.  I should add the build pipeline was created using "classic" editor rather than YAML.

The build report is the following:

```
Starting: Build solution
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
==============================================================================
"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.214.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -latest -format json
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.214.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=289fdd5e-8a3a-4f93-b828-4d1258871307|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.214.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\\" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="17.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_bbd45d84-e1e3-43e0-afab-c6da9b77da75_build_13_0"
Build started 9/6/2023 6:43:26 PM.

Project "D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
##[error]D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\1\Winnings\Winnings.CoreData\Winnings.CoreData.csproj" was not found.
D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\1\Winnings\Winnings.CoreData\Winnings.CoreData.csproj" was not found. [D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln]
##[error]D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\1\Winnings\WinningsDataAccess\WinningsDataAccess.csproj" was not found.
D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\1\Winnings\WinningsDataAccess\WinningsDataAccess.csproj" was not found. [D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln]
Project "D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\WinningsAPI.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
```

I have tried adjusting the security permissions in the Winnings repository to Read Allow for build pipeline.  This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use multiple repositories unless it is a YAML.

This link might help you to use Multiple repos and refer to the other projects in your pipeline - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

A sample YAML for Building a Dotnet project is here - https://github.com/boga5/dotnet-sample/blob/main/azure-pipelines.yml

Another way could be to publish a project as a NuGet package and refer to this package in other projects. So it'll fetch the package before building your project.
This could be an extra maintenance if your dependent project is updated regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you referenced project which is not available during build.

It works locally, because you have both repositories fetched.

Since you use classic pipeline this is not easy to fetch another repository.

[image]

Ideally you should have:

- both projects in the same repository
- publish nuget package `Winnings`, so later `WinningsAPI` could reference nuget package instead of the project itself

In YAML pipelines you can also try fetch both repositories and build that way.

But please consider joining these two project into one repository. Is there any reason to keep them separate?

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?